# Android:About the sample rate when recording when using AudioRecord and OpenSL ES

Tags: android, audiorecord, opensl

I am investigating the audio recording using AudioRecord and OpenSL ES, and I find some confusion about the sample rate when reading the doc.

About the [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#AudioRecord(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), it says

> the sample rate expressed in Hertz. **44100Hz** is currently the only rate that is guaranteed to work on all devices, but other rates such as 22050, 16000, and 11025 may work on some devices. SAMPLE_RATE_UNSPECIFIED means to use a route-dependent value which is usually the sample rate of the source. getSampleRate() can be used to retrieve the actual sample rate chosen.

So 44100 is more preferred, but when using [OpenSL ES](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/opensl-for-android.html):

> The configurations that OpenSL ES for Android supports for recording are device-dependent; usually, **16,000 Hz** mono/16-bit signed is available regardless of the device.

Why using OpenSL ES gives the different recommend sample rate with AudioRecord? Don't they use the same hardware?